# Persisting a one-to-one relation using Spring Data JPA does not work

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

i am working with the following tutorial [Spring Data REST](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) to access database entries via a REST Api, provided by Spring.

So right now i got the following Entity classes

**Products**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "products" )
public class ProductsEntity implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@JoinColumn(name="Units_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name="Units_id")    
private UnitsEntity unitsEntity;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column( name = "idproducts" )
private Long idProducts;

@Column(name = "productname" )
private String productName;

@Column (name = "Units_id")
private Long unitsid;

public ProductsEntity(){}

// Getter and setter

}
```

**Units**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "units")
public class UnitsEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="unit")
private String unit;

@Column(name="units_id")
private Long units_id;

// Getter and Setter
}
```

As you can see there is a One to one relation between Products and Units

And right now i **can** retrieve products with the correct units but i can't persist it via  the REST API. It says there is `No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class ..db.entities.ProductsEntity from request with content type of application/json!`

Do i need a `HttpMessageConverter` or is there a wrong or missing configuration element in my classes?!

** Edit: **

The JSON Requests looks like this (the unitsEntity is an existing entity):

```
{
    "productName": "Äpfel12342344",
        "unitsEntity": {
        "unit" : "Anzahl",
        "units_id" : 1
     }
}
```

But now i get the following exception: 
`"Could not read JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: ...db.entities.ProductsEntity["unitsEntity"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: ...db.entities.ProductsEntity["unitsEntity"])"`

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes, some days ago i wrote a mapper, that mapps the product to a resource object with primitive datatypes.